# Unable to collect data from additional textbox created by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to collect data entered inside textboxes wrapped in div within a form.I'm using session to gather an array of data passed by the submit button. However it only captures the very first row of data. I believe data entered in textboxes created by javascript not recognised?

HTML
       
         
       Entry 1

```
   <input type="text" name="myInputs_d[]" size='5' style='margin:4px;'>D(mm)
   <input type="text" name="myInputs_d1[]" size='5' style='margin:4px;'>D1(mm)
   <input type="text" name="myInputs_bags[]" size='5' style='margin:4px;'>Bags
   <input type="text" name="myInputs_carton[]" size='5' style='margin:4px;'>Cartons

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>    
  <input type="button" value="Add another text input"  onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

javascript to create multiple textboxes

```
<script>
var counter = 1;
var limit = 10;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <input type='text' name='myInputs_d[]' size='5' style='margin:5px;'>D(mm)<input type='text' name='myInputs_d1[]' size='5' style='margin:5px;'>D1(mm)<input type='text' name='myInputs_bags[]' size='5' style='margin:5px;'>Bags<input type='text' name='myInputs_carton[]' size='5' style='margin:5px;'>Cartons";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

          counter++;
     }
}
</script>
```

Php to echo all the data entered

```
$_SESSION['myInputs_all'][]=array($_POST["myInputs_d"],$_POST["myInputs_d1"],$_POST["myInputs_bags"],$_POST["myInputs_carton"]);
print_r($_SESSION['myInputs_all']);
foreach ($myInputs_all  as $eachInput) 
{
  echo $eachInput . "<br>";

}
```

I might have entered three sets of records ,but when I print_r($_SESSION['myInputs_all']);..... it only shows the first record like this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 20 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 20 ) )
```

Comment: check only $_SESSION in print_r function like this print_r($_SESSION)

Comment: i don't see anything wrong in this, unless to tried to just input one row

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` look like?

Comment: @MunshiAzhar, it displays all the session variable but the used in the page.However for the textbox item still one row only it shows

Comment: @Travesty3 , it displays all the POST variable but the used in the page.However for the textbox item still one row only it shows

Comment: I'm not sure why you're having trouble. I'm assuming you've omitted your `<form>` tags and your submit button from the code snippet. Hopefully you have those. Provided that you do, [here is an example that shows that it should work](http://jsfiddle.net/qe63p4cg/). The example doesn't actually submit the form, because jsFiddle can't really handle form submissions (there is no back-end code I can write for this). But it does show what data the form has in it. The dynamically created fields are part of what is sent with form submission, so your code should work.

Comment: @Travesty3, I already have <form> tag and submit button in it, I just didn't post because it's too long

Comment: @veronicageorge: Did you look at that jsFiddle that shows that your code should work? Do you see any difference that might fix your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code

JavaScript:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 10;
function addInput(divName){

 if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }
 else {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var stringInput = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <input type='text'           name='myInputs_d[]' size='5' style='margin:5px;'>D(mm)<input type='text' name='myInputs_d1[]' size='5' style='margin:5px;'>D1(mm)<input type='text' name='myInputs_bags[]' size='5' style='margin:5px;'>Bags<input type='text' name='myInputs_carton[]' size='5' style='margin:5px;'>Cartons";
    newDiv.innerHTML = stringInput;
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newDiv);
    counter++;
 }
}
```

Your HTML should look like this. ( Add form tag and submit button )

```
<form name="test" method="post" action="">
<div id="dynamicInput">

Entry 1

<input type="text" name="myInputs_d[]" size='5' style='margin:4px;'>D(mm)
<input type="text" name="myInputs_d1[]" size='5' style='margin:4px;'>D1(mm)
<input type="text" name="myInputs_bags[]" size='5' style='margin:4px;'>Bags
<input type="text" name="myInputs_carton[]" size='5' style='margin:4px;'>Cartons

</div>

<input type="button" value="Add another text input"  onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>
```

and in Last your php code should look like this:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){

$_SESSION['myInputs_all'] = array($_POST["myInputs_d"],$_POST["myInputs_d1"],$_POST["myInputs_bags"],$_POST["myInputs_carton"]);

print_r($_SESSION['myInputs_all']);
echo "<br>";
foreach( $_SESSION['myInputs_all'] as $all_inputs ){

    foreach( $all_inputs as $inputs ){
        echo $inputs.'<br>';
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Well my html code already has form tag, I just replace my javascript and php as yours but it still displays only one row

Comment: I studied your code and I found that you are setting your session variable as array and your POST variables are also in array means that your session variable stores multidimensional array. so that first I loop out the session variable and than loop out your POST variables which are in session's array.

Comment: it works ..but how to make the foreach echo set of row by row.. I mean to display the first 4 columns of data and then following the next.

Comment: For displaying data row by row can try below code `$counter = count( $_POST['myInputs_d']);` and your for and foreach loop like this. `for( $c = 0; $c < $counter; $c++ ){ foreach( $myInputs_all as $all_inputs ){ echo $all_inputs[$c].' '; } echo '<br>'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not properly iterating over all elements, here is my suggestion:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($myInputs_all); ++$i) {
    for($j = 0; $j < (count($myInputs_all[$i])-1); ++$j) {
        for($k = 0; $k < 4; ++$k) {
            print "i:$i; j:$j; k:$k";
            print $myInputs_all[$i][$k][$j] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but doesn't echo anything,//for the additional info starts



$_SESSION['myInputs_all'] = array($_POST["myInputs_d"],$_POST["myInputs_d1"],$_POST["myInputs_bags"],$_POST["myInputs_carton"]);

for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['myInputs_all']); ++$i) {
    for($j = 0; $j < (count($_SESSION['myInputs_all'][$i])-1); ++$j) {
        for($k = 0; $k < 4; ++$k) {
            print "i:$i; j:$j; k:$k";
            print $_SESSION['myInputs_all'][$i][$k][$j] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}//for the additional info ends

Comment: I tried your loop but it generate many notices for undefined index.